# Bind9 different answer per ip, possible?

Tags: bind

Is it possible to configure bind9 so it would answer with different A record depending on client ip?

Probably not, as dns servers do propagate and it's never direct hit, but worth to ask.

Example:

Let's say I got domain.com with nameserver ns1.domain.com... when people with ip 217.*.*.* go to domain.com would like it to serve 217.1.1.1 and people with ip 218.*.*.* should get served 218.1.1.1. Of course it's only an example. Can't be redirect. Has to be answer by dns server.

Answer (score 4):

Bind has a feature called **views** that allow you to provide different versions of a zone, based on the source IP of the DNS request.

Bind views are done for a zone, not for individual records, which can be annoying if you only want to adjust one record out of hundreds in a zone.

Links

- http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html
- https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00851/0/Understanding-views-in-BIND-9-by-example.html
- http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly/networking/news/views_0501.html

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear enough... I mean... that my domain has a nameserver that is bind... is it possible to redirect people with given ip to different A record than all rest?

Comment: I think you achieve such granularity with the [*response policy zone*](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/rpz.html) rather than views

Comment: @FlashThunder, Unfortunately your comment hasn't really cleared up or changed anything for me.  Please feel free to **edit** additional details into your question.  It might be more useful if you can give a specific example of what you want the requests and replies to look like.